# How to set UIImageView value from a String in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am parsing a Remote XML file and storing the values in an `NSArray`. From the array I am using `NSScanner` to get a particular image and allotting it to `UIImageView`.

After scanning and getting the URL link of an image, I am assigning it to a `UIImageView` but it's not showing the image. I am getting only a blank white window. The code is shown below:

**MyViewController**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myXML.com/Category.xml"];
AGSParser *parser = [[AGSParser alloc] init];
if ([parser loadXMLByURL:url]){
   self.xmlProductsResults = parser.products;
   NSArray *myArray = [_xmlProductsResults objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *string = [myArray description];
   NSString *url = nil;
   NSScanner *parser = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
  [parser scanUpToString:@"imageUrlString" intoString:nil];
  if (![parser isAtEnd]) {
     [parser scanUpToString:@"=" intoString:nil];
     NSCharacterSet *charset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\"'"];
    [parser scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:nil];
    [parser scanCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:nil];
    [parser scanUpToCharactersFromSet:charset intoString:&url];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@",url);
 }
}
```

When I check in `NSLog` I am getting the string value as `http://myimage.com/image1.png`. After this in my View Controller I am assigning this image url to UIImageView like this:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:url];
```

Here the image is not assigned. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `[UIImage imageNamed:url]` into `[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]]`.

For your other problem, look at V-Xtreme's answer

Comment: it shows me a warning `Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSURL *'`

Comment: my simulator shows a black screen nothing more than that and my log shows `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch` can you tell why happens so

Comment: That has to do with your .xib window and view controller not being set up properly

Comment: am using ios6 with story boards

Comment: In your project summary is your storyboard set up as the main storyboard?

Comment: check the tutorial V-Xtreme commented

Answer (score 3):

```
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
```

this happens when have not given the root view controller that is starting window in your app delegate class.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: am using ios6 with storyboards where can i configure the above code

Comment: here is nice tutorial of storyboard http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1